# React apply style to element using a wrapper

Tags: animation, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
<FadeInAnimation>
    <SomeReactElement />
</FadeInAnimation>
```

The react element could be:

```
SomeReactElement.render = ()=>{

   return <div>hi</div>

}
```

The FadeInAnimation just interpolates a style object and passes it to its child via `React.cloneElement(this.props.children ...).`

The problem is that the `SomeReactElement` cannot process a style prop properly (since it needs to know to which HTML tag element (such as div) to apply it onto).

I could just pass the `{...props}` to the div but then in more complex hierarchies such as

```
 <ReactElement1>
     <ReactElement2>
        <SomeReactElement />
     </ReactElement2>
 </ReactElement1>
```

This becomes cumbersome.

What I'd really like is a convenience method that I could use in the FadeInAnimation component that could find the outer most React element which is of an HTML tag type.

I can't react it via this.props.children because the div is not `SomeReactElement`'s child.

I'm aware that I could wrap the element within a  or  but it breaks the design in many cases.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, are you trying to pass down different styles to SomeReactElement, which you want to apply to different elements by tag type?

Comment: What I'm trying is to have a generic behvaiour in the `FadeInAnimation` object, so when it passes the `style` object which holds the current interpolated opacity value to its children, it does not care whether it's a complex React element such as `SomeReactElement` which cannot take styling directly or it's a simple element such as `div` which can be styled directly.

Comment: What kind of component can't be styled directly?

Comment: Components such as `SomeReactElement`. If you pass them a style prop, they can't tell to which of their child elements they should apply it to.

Comment: I think they could: any react component can and must render only one component (div or whatever), and the passed down style could therefore always be applied to the top element in the render function.

Comment: Think of a component which renders as follows

      <Component>
               <ComponentA>
                     <ComponentB>
                           <div/>
</ComponentB></ComponentA></Component>


Now, given that I'm wrapping `Component` with the `FadeInAnimation` component, the `FadeInAnimation` component needs to know to which element it should pass the style to (the answer is the internal div, but `FadeInAnimation` has no access to it - and that's my problem)

Comment: Why wouldn't you pass the style down from Component to whatever child you want to give it to as a prop?

Comment: It is possible but I'm trying to achieve a generic behaviour, rather than having to address the possibility of a component being animated. From my point of view, the component shouldn't be aware whether it is animated or not. Also, it is repetitive code, since the algorithm ("just find the next html tag and apply the animated style onto it") is the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating a simpler problem :)

If you want to implement a `FadeAnimation` component, it could simply **wrap all it's children** and animate that wrapper. Voilà!

Here's a pen with a complete example: http://codepen.io/gadr90/pen/Gpwdbq?editors=011

Basically:

```
const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup

const FadeAnimation = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
        transitionName="example" 
        transitionEnterTimeout={500} 
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
        {this.props.show &&
          <div key="content">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        }
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }
})

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { show: false }
  },

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle</button>

        <FadeAnimation show={this.state.show}>
          <div key="content">Content</div>
        </FadeAnimation>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

And for CSS:

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```